# YAML with Anchors ... how to combine?

Tags: docker, yaml

Hi all this is my situation

```
x-service-setting: &service-settings
  environment:
    - RabbitMQ:HostName=rabbitmq
    - RabbitMQ:Port=5672
    - RabbitMQ:VirtualHost=/
```

and I am going to create multiple instance of this service, different services have different post endpoint.

```
  service_1:
    container_name: service_1
    <<: *service-settings
    environment:
      - EndPoint : service_1 Endpoint
  

  sercices_2:
    container_name: sercices_2
    <<: *service-settings
    environment:
      - EndPoint : service_2 Endpoint
```

Is that possible to be like below ?

```
  environment:
    - RabbitMQ:HostName=rabbitmq
    - RabbitMQ:Port=5672
    - RabbitMQ:VirtualHost=/
    - EndPoint : service_1 Endpoint
```

```
  environment:
    - RabbitMQ:HostName=rabbitmq
    - RabbitMQ:Port=5672
    - RabbitMQ:VirtualHost=/
    - EndPoint : service_2 Endpoint
```

Answer (score 1):

The [YAML merge key](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html) only works on mappings. It does not merge recursively; it just doesn't do anything for keys that already exist in the current mapping (which is the case in your code).

You will need a templating engine like Jinja (commonly used with YAML, e.g. in Ansible or SaltStack) to do such processing.